# Are /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all and net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all equivalent?

Tags: kernel, proc

According to the following test, it seems that `net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all` and `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` are exactly the same. Are they exactly the same? If so, which way is the best to use?

```
$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
1
$ sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all <<< 0
0
$ sysctl net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [`man sysctl`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/sysctl.8) (emphasis mine):

```
sysctl is used to modify kernel parameters at runtime.  The parameters available are those
listed under /proc/sys/.  Procfs is required for sysctl support in  Linux.   You  can  use
sysctl to both read and write sysctl data.
```

It depends on what you want to do. For one-off changes, I suppose it makes no difference. For maintaining a configuration, `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/sysctl.d` are much more convenient.